Deriving a boundary function with desired attributes
I am training a neural network to predict the output of a structural system. Suppose the output of the network is $N(x)$, the output needs satisfy certain boundary condition of the structural system. Suppose for example the boundary condition is $u(0)=0$, I could then modify the output of the network to be:
$$
u(x)=xN(x)
$$
And the output would always satisfy the boundary condition, regardless of the value of $N(0)$. This is beneficial as I don't need to use a loss function for the boundary condition to train the network on, which greatly speeds up convergence.
In my case, the boundary I have is a pin support at an end, so the boundary conditions are:
$$
\begin{align}
u(0)&=0 \text{ Displacement is zero}\\\\
u'(0)&\neq 0 \text{ Angle is non-zero}\\\\
u''(0)&=0 \text{ Moment is zero}\\\\
u'''(0)&\neq 0 \text{ Shear force is non-zero}
\end{align}
$$
I have found a function that satisfies these conditions on its own (e.g. $B(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$), however if I do:
$$
\begin{align}
u(x)&=B(x)N(x)\\\\
u(0)&=0 \text{ Works for displacement}\\\\
u'(x)&=B'(x)N(x)+B(x)N'(x)\\\\
u'(0)&=N(x)\neq 0 \text{ Works for angle}\\\\
u''(x)&=B''(x)N(x)+2B'(x)N'(x)+B(x)N''(x)\\\\
u''(0)&=2N'(x)\neq 0 \text{ Does not work for moment}
\end{align}
$$
As you can see, it doesn't work for moment because of the non-zero $B'(0)$ term, from the product rule. Thinking about this more generally, suppose $B$ is a function composition of $N$, then:
$$
\begin{align}
u(x)&=B(N(x))\\\\
u'(x)&=N'(x)B'(N(x))\\\\
u''(x)&=N'(x)^2B''(N(x))+N''(x)B'(N(x))
\end{align}
$$
The only way to enforce that $u''(0)=0$ is to ensure that $B'(N(0))=0$ and $B''(N(0))=0$, but doing this will also enforce that $u'(0)=0$, which violates the angle being free (this more generalised formulation is problematic too as $N(0)$ can potentially change). Is there any way to get around this issue? Some way to modify the output of the network so that the boundary conditions are always satisfied?
